# Unexpected behaviour with Java unboxing

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive-types, unboxing

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, 1);
int value = map.get(2);
System.out.println(v);
```

On executing the above code I find below exception
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

but if place an Integer in the place int primitive type in the 3rd line, all working well. So, the question in here is why doesn't java unboxing take care of this null value internally and assign null to variable called value?

Comment: Use `Integer` not `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, the question in here is why doesn't java unboxing take care of this null value internally and assign null to variable called value?

Your `value` variable is an `int` primitive. A primitive cannot have a `null` value. Only objects can.

Comment: Yeah, I missed this basic fundamental point. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a primitive type.

`null` is not a primitive type, it represents a nonexistent object reference and cannot be autoboxed to a primitive type.

`int value = null;` which could be seen as more "explicit" version of the question  you asking for, does not even compile.